# How were those questions modified by 1 rep user Megan?

Tags: support

I just stumbled up a few questions that were marked as modified by user [Megan](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/25765/megan).

[image: Questions modified by Megan]

Looking into one of them ([Contract Management](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/25999/contract-management)), I can't see any changes:

[image: No changes in Contract Management]

How can he have changed so many questions with 1 rep only and what were those changes?

Comment: Megan is most likely a *she.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are deleted answers from Megan on those questions. The system counts this as a modification, and it isn't reset when the answer is deleted.